# Harvard referencing - Multiple Authors

Tags: citations, citation-style

I am using Harvard referencing for my thesis draft, however, I am a bit confused with how to cite multiple authors (4 or more) in the bibliography. Specifically, I have been finding contradicting sources. Here: https://www.scribbr.co.uk/faqs/multiple-authors-in-harvard-style/ they mention to use "First Author name et al.", while here:https://library-guides.ucl.ac.uk/harvard/authors the include all the Authors' names. I understand that there are several Harvard versions but is there a guide I can use to be sure I am being consistent to a specific version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should follow the guide issued by the institution to which you'll be submitting the thesis.  If that's UCL, you've already found it.

Comment: Thanks very much for your response, I took a look at my university's guidelines, it's just that they are not too extensive, I'll see if I can find more documentation.